# How do I skip a observer after_save call while testing in Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, observer-pattern

There are some API calls to external services in the after_save method in my PostObserver. But I don't want to invoke after_save while testing with Rspec. Is there a way to do that? Thank you.

It's Rails 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stub it out:

```
PostObserver.instance.stub(:after_save => true)
```

Comment: this reminds me of using PostObserver.any_instance.stubs(:after_save => true); thank you :)

Answer (score 12):

Stubbing observers can cause unwanted side-effects because they are singletons. An alternative in Rails 3.1 is to [disable](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/ObserverArray.html#method-i-disable) the observer in your test. e.g.

```
Post.observers.disable :all do
  ..
end
```

Another option for older versions of Rails is the [no-peeping-toms](https://github.com/patmaddox/no-peeping-toms) gem.